# Как получить название папки из  boost::filesystem::path?

Tags: macos, boost, c++

Я организую передачу списка директорий из директории some_dir в сокет:

```
 boost::filesystem::path some_dir("/some_path/some_path2");
 boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_iter;
 for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir_iter(some_dir); dir_iter != end_iter; ++dir_iter) {
   if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(dir_iter->status())) {
     boost::filesystem::path p(dir_iter->path());

     int i = (int) p.filename().string().size(); //получаем размер p в байтах
     string str_size = boost::lexical_cast<string>(i);
     sock.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(str_size.c_str(), 4)); //отправляем сначала размер названия папки
     sock.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(p.stem().c_str(), p.filename().string().size()));
     }
    }
```

Данный метод работает не полностью - дело в том, что если находиться папка, у которой есть расширения, к примеру */user/user.1*, то расширения (в данном случае *"1"*) отпадает и название папки уходит не целиком. 
Откусывает расширение по моему метод `filename()`. Как выйти из данного положения?

Comment: Хм, может быть, `user` — папка, а `user.1` — файл?

Comment: Нашел - в последней строке надо было оказывается вместо `...buffer(p.stem.c_str()...` тоже писать `...buffer(p.filename().c_str...`